# Using Webpack for simple site

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack to work for the first time and I'm doing it on a simple website but, no matter what I try, it never works correctly. I've been stuck on it for weeks and I've seriously tried every thread out there to no avail. I just need someone who doesn't have a problem with webpack to look at my code and provide comment on how to get it to work correctly.

I have all my source code in the src directory. Libraries and developer dependencies are in the node_modules directory. And I want to run webpack and have it output everything to the dist directory. If I run a server using only the files in the src directory, it works fine but as soon as I run webpack and try to use the files in the dist directory, it all falls apart.

Here's webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + "\\src",
debug: true,
entry: "./index.webpack.js",
output: {
    path: __dirname + "\\dist",
    filename: "index.min.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader:'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets:['es2015']
            }
        },
        {
            test:/\.css$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader:'style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test:/\.less$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader:'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
        },
        {
            test:/\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        },
        {
            test:/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true'
        },
        {
            test:/\.html$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
]
```

};

And my entry point is index.webpack.js:

```
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./index.html');
require('jQuery');
require('bootstrap');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./css/footer.css');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./css/header.css');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./css/styles.css');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./fonts/HelveticaRounded-Black.eot');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./fonts/HelveticaRounded-Black.svg');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./fonts/HelveticaRounded-Black.ttf');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./fonts/HelveticaRounded-Black.woff');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/butterfly.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/dr photo.jpg');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/firefly.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/footerspikes.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/mainheaderimage.jpg');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/mushrooms.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/teethkids.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./img/titlebanner.gif');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./refs/footer.html');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./refs/header.html');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./refs/leftmargin.html');
require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./refs/rightmargin.html');
```

What do you think?

--edited after trying first answer--

my updated webpack.config.js:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var commonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
var cleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    debug: true,
    entry: {
        entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.webpack.js'),
        vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrapjs']
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'jquery', 'dist', 'jquery.min.js'),
            'bootstrapjs': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap', 'dist', 'js', 'bootstrap.min.js')
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].bundle.min.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader:'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader:'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
                test:/\.less$/,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader:'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
            },
            {
                test:/\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test:/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000!img?progressive=true'
            },
            {
                test:/\.html$/,
                include:path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        inline: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    plugins: debug ? [
        new cleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'pages', 'index.html'),
            hash: true,
            chunks: 'commons'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: "jquery", 
            jQuery: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery"
        }),
        new commonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['commons', 'vendor', 'bootstrap']
        })
    ] : [
        new cleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'pages', 'index.html'),
            hash: true,
            chunks: 'commons'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: "jquery", 
            jQuery: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery"
        }),
        new commonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['commons', 'vendor', 'bootstrap']
        })
    ]
};
```

My index.webpack.js is now an empty file.

I'm basically still having the exact same problems as before only I'm using html-webpack-plugin instead of requiring all my files in the entry file.

$ is not defined even though I'm defining it with provideplugin.

bootstrap css isn't going through and it doesn't work when I put it in the vendors list.

any ideas?

Comment: Never heard of webpack but just take a look at it........ speechless. I don't think it makes projects easier to maintain. Why you want to use this anyway?

Comment: I already took a look at it. I went through like every thread and nothing seems to be working for me. I want to use it for a couple reasons: 1. so I can code in less/es6 and have it automatically precompile it. and 2. so it can automatically minify everything and remove unused library methods/comments. Then the minified/smaller/faster files will be posted to the web host instead of the larger developer files.

Comment: This is not an errorproof method, silly way to manage output. There are much easier ways to do that without changing any line of code or writing a complex cfg file. You have to do this server side. I wrote it myself but there are other parties like google that provide a minification module/plugin for your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Since your starting out, now would be a good time to switch to Webpack 2 and https://webpack.js.org/ for the documentation, which is currently in beta and you can install it using the `beta` distribution tag via:

```
npm install webpack@beta --save
```

Great, now take a deep breath and let's try to get the next point through: you have to forget about serving your raw application sources and assets and always point your web server to the output directory (or simply use `webpack-dev-server`). Let me try to explain.

Webpack is a module bundler that agressive on optimization for distribution and almost all of it's features depend on module loaders. What module loaders do is they take your static references to your sources or assets and they produce a JS module. Oprah show: CSS sources get a JS module and PNGs get a JS module and MP3s get a JS module--everyone gets a module \o/. This might trip you up if you're used to simply authoring your sources, dropping in assets and pointing your web server to the root and statically referecing these from HTML, because it won't work with Webpack.

Using `file-loader` like this won't get you anywhere, because you're doing nothing with the output. Remember I said that everything gets a module and what `file-loader` produces is a module that exports a string to some asset that's in the output. So first thing you have to start doing is start taking those outputs and then inject them into the HTML to get the actual references.

You should consider using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to produce the necessary HTML template and require other assets as necessary in your JS sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't seem to figure this out to save my life. See that I edited my initial question with updated files. Should I be requiring my css in the entry file or in the html template?

Comment: You can safely import stylesheets either from your main module or a template engine that supports `require` from templates. The style loader will create a JS module will include code that dynamically inserts a `style` tag into the document.

Comment: @333OnlyHalfEvil try not to get yourself bogged down with all the details on how Webpack works. Look around GitHub, find some boilerplate projects that support the kind of stack you use (frameworks for JS applications, styles, etc.) and then slowly fork off with your own changes.

Comment: Still can't get it. I got the css through without error (finally) but now I can't get my header and footer references through. I was trying the handlebars-loader and using a .hbs as the template in html-webpack-plugin but images won't make it through for some reason. Any ideas? I opened another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103241/handlebars-template-with-webpack-problems

Comment: Have you gotten html-webpack-plugin to work while using separate header and footer html files to be referenced in?

Comment: I'm starting to feel like maybe that's the wrong way to think about it. Should I be just using a React component for the headers/footers or is that overkill?

Comment: @333OnlyHalfEvil did you fix your problem?

Comment: Nope. :(. Any input?

Comment: It's okay if you don't want to tell me. I'll figure it out eventually. Been busy with something else and was hoping someone would post some more insight in the meantime. I've tried so many different ways now, all littered with errors, and I was hoping I could get some confirmation from someone saying they successfully did it a certain way. Apparently any way works since if I ask the header/footer thing as a question it gets hit by moderators as being "too broad". Sigh. I guess right now my choices are: 1) react routes into separate html pages, and 2) program the entry file to handle it somehow

Comment: 3) figure out something with handlebars, 4) figure out something with the ejs template (same/different as handlebars?) 5) figure out how to just copy over the reference files

Comment: Well apparently I can't figure it out.

Comment: I literally get a page full of errors every time I try anything at all and that's been happening since the beginning. sigh