# Handlebars template with webpack problems

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Handlebars templates to work with webpack. I feel like I've tried everything I can try and just get errors left and right and don't know what to do or what to try to figure out next and am hoping someone can help me.

I'm trying to use a handlebars template that includes references to header.hbs and footer.hbs but can't seem to get it to work properly no matter what I try. I started out using the template with html-webpack-plugin directly as in the following thread: [Html Webpack Plugin - How do you import headers/footer html partials into body template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763778/html-webpack-plugin-how-do-you-import-headers-footer-html-partials-into-body-t) to no avail. They're saying it works for them but it doesn't work for me. It kinda works but images don't make it through. (I was using handlebars-loader).

I tried switching the loader to handlebars-template-loader. Still didn't work

I tried using handlebars-webpack-plugin insteal of html-webpack-plugin and I just get errors even though I'm using the same configuration in the docs. What gives?

What route should I go? Can anyone get webpack to work with a handlebars template that has partial references to header/footer that contains images? If so, what's your setup?

Comment: I'd like to comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763778/html-webpack-plugin-how-do-you-import-headers-footer-html-partials-into-body-t?noredirect=1&lq=1 saying this won't get any images through and ask how but I can't since I don't have 50 reputation :(

Comment: While doing it the handlebars-loader way, I'm referencing the partials as {{> ../partials/header.hbs}} etc. If the header, footer, etc, is an hbs file, the loader will plug it into the template fine but it's not using any loaders on the images and isn't minifying the html from the template. If I try to switch header and footer to html then I get an error saying that "The partial ../partials/header.html could not be compiled when running in runtime-only mode"